# How to add a value to an existing model record with the use of Django Forms?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to make a form that adds points to a user's account. This form chooses which user  and it should add it based on the value added. I don't know what I did wrong. No hints in the terminal to show what I did wrong. I just doesn't submit. The only indication that I screwed up is it shows that `!form.is_valid` based on the error message that I set.

Here is my forms.py:

```
class addpointForm(forms.ModelForm):
add_point_field = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput)
class Meta:
    model = Points
    fields = ['user']
```

Here is my views.py:

```
def pointform(request):
if request.method=='POST':
    form = addpointForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = request.user
        messages.success(request, 'Success! Points has been added!')
        instance.points += addpointForm.add_point_field
        instance.save()
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Oh no! Points has an error!')

form = addpointForm()
return render (request,'users/addpoints.html',{'form':form})
```

I just some help to point me in the right direction. Any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: What validation error message you have got in your forms?

Comment: It pops the error 'Oh no! Points has an error!' in my form the message that I made to indicated that `form.is_valid()` is false. Other than that I don't why the form is invalid.

Comment: what is the result of `print(form.errors)` in your *...else clasuse* ?

Comment: I think it's because of this statement:
`if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = request.user
        messages.success(request, 'Success! Points has been added!')
        instance.points += addpointForm.add_point_field
        instance.save()`